# How can I implement this method to prevent from sql injection? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you all

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, snowflake-stage

I am trying to stage a file in snowflake using JdbcTemplate.execute() but I don't know how protect it against sql injection.

```
private void stageFile(String fpath){
    template.execute("PUT file://" + fpath + " @SnowFlakeStage AUTO_COMPRESS=FALSE");
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but I am going to take a guess. Would something like `Url url = new Url("file://" + fpath)` do the trick? Then you can do something like `execute("PUT " + url.getFile() + ....)`.

Comment: My other guess is to use `File file = new File(fpath);`.